# erro #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I can't create a table.

This is the code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `monitoreos`;

CREATE TABLE `monitoreos` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha` VARCHAR NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_cliente` INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_vehiculo` INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `posicion` INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero_serie` INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero_alterno` INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `profundidad_inicial` VARCHAR NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `horometro_actual` VARCHAR NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `profundidad_actual_exterior` VARCHAR NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `profundidad_actual_interior` VARCHAR NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

and this is the error:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_cliente` INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_vehiculo` I' at line 3
```

Comment: Why is `id` set to both `NOT NULL` and `DEFAULT NULL`?

Comment: `fecha VARCHAR NULL DEFAULT NULL` is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nullable and `DEFAULT NULL` are the defaults, so you can remove them.

More importantly, you need a length for the `VARCHAR` fields.  The following works:

```
CREATE TABLE `monitoreos` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `fecha` VARCHAR(255),
  `id_cliente` INTEGER,
  `id_vehiculo` INTEGER,
  `posicion` INTEGER,
  `numero_serie` INTEGER,
  `numero_alterno` INTEGER,
  `profundidad_inicial` VARCHAR(255),
  `horometro_actual` VARCHAR(255),
  `profundidad_actual_exterior` VARCHAR(255),
  `profundidad_actual_interior` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0976) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: `fecha` should probably be declared `DATE`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can put default Null and auto increment together. Get rid of the Default Null.